# Genexus-¿Cómo obtener el usuario creado en GAM en tiempo real que se ha logueado?

Tags: genexus, genexus18

```
Usuario = &GAMSession.User.Name + &GAMUser.GetName() + &GAMUser.Name.FromString()
    if CotizacionUsuario.IsEmpty();
```

He probado de estas maneras pero no he podido, por algun motivo no llena el dato o en este caso el atributo ya que estoy en las rules de una transacción.

Comment: ¿Qué version de GX estás utilizando y qué generador? ¿Utilizas algun pattern? Si revisas la navegación del objeto, ¿no muestra ningun warning del tipo "Rule _______ not included"?

Comment: Si usas variables deben estar previamente instaciadas, de lo contrario estarán vacías como cualquier variable. Te estaría faltando hacer previamente &GamSession = GamSession.Get(). O si son reglas de una transacción directamente utilizar el EO. Estás usando gamsession y gamuser, podés hacer todo directamente: ej:  Usuario = GamUser.GetName() ;

Answer (score 2):

Para poder obtener el usuario lo he conseguido de la siguente manera:

```
Usuario = GAMUser.GetName();
```